# How can I parse the Makefile using awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am novice to awk scripting. I need help in figuring out a way to parse the makefile.

Below is my sample make file. I use "make tests" to run my tests. All the test files listed under "LTESTS=". Here, I have listed only 3 files (connect, proxy-connect, connect-privsep) but in reality I have 70 files. How can I fetch all the files listed in "LTESTS=".

I searched but couldn't figureout a way to extract. Thanks for your help.

```
    REGRESS_TARGETS=    t-exec
tests:      prep $(REGRESS_TARGETS)

prep:
    test "x${USE_VALGRIND}" = "x" || mkdir -p $(OBJ)/valgrind-out

LTESTS=     connect \
        proxy-connect \
        connect-privsep



t-exec: ${LTESTS:=.sh}
    @if [ "x$?" = "x" ]; then exit 0; fi; \
    for TEST in ""$?; do \
        echo "run test $${TEST}" ... 1>&2; \
        (env SUDO="${SUDO}" TEST_ENV=${TEST_ENV} ${TEST_SHELL} ${.CURDIR}/test-exec.sh ${.OBJDIR} ${.CURDIR}/$${TEST}) || exit $$?; \
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just rewrite your field separator like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
    FS = "[ \t=]*(\\\\[ \t]*\r?\n[ \t]*)?"
    RS = "" 
}
$1 == "LTESTS" { 
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i 
}
' Makefile
```

Note that `RS = ""` means it expects a blank line before and after LTESTS.

Output:

```
connect
proxy-connect
connect-privsep
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'sub(/.*LTESTS=/,""){f=1} !NF{f=0} f{print $1}' file
connect
proxy-connect
connect-privsep
```

or if you don't have a blank line after the LTESTS block:

```
awk 'sub(/.*LTESTS=/,""){f=1} f{print $1; if (!/\\/) exit}' file
```

Comment: This will not even work if LTESTS contains two values in single line. Like this `LTESTS = connect proxy-connect`.

Comment: If the OP has to deal with that situation (or any other she hasn't told us about yet, e.g. if LTESTS can be lower case or if FOOLTESTS can exist or she has file names with spaces in the list or ....) then she needs to update her posted example to show it.